# How to reference a local cell in QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I just about have formula 100% perfect.  Just one issue:

Formula (Works):

```
=QUERY( ImportRange( "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lf4r_b0fmFh6fClZsGmfZmo8ZD87qf8N_0f-Jaoyu-g/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A1:AA1000" ) , 
 "Select Col19 where Col8 = 2917", 0)
```

Instead of the `"Select X Where Y = Z"`

I am hoping **Z** can be a value on the current sheet.

Example: (not working)

```
=QUERY( ImportRange( "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lf4r_b0fmFh6fClZsGmfZmo8ZD87qf8N_0f-Jaoyu-g/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A1:AA1000" ) , 
 "Select Col19 where Col8 = "Sheet1!F5"", 0)
```

Sheets sees the reference to Cell F5 but still gives a `"Formula parse error"`

Can Value **Z** be a linked cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value **Z** is numeric do:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Lf4r_b0fmFh6fClZsGmfZmo8ZD87qf8N_0f-Jaoyu-g", "Sheet1!A1:P1000"), 
 "select Col19 where Col8 = "&Sheet1!F5, 0)
```

---

If the value **Z** is a text string or a mix of text and numbers do:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Lf4r_b0fmFh6fClZsGmfZmo8ZD87qf8N_0f-Jaoyu-g", "Sheet1!A1:P1000"), 
 "select Col19 where Col8 = '"&Sheet1!F5&"'", 0)
```